# how to solve laravel error 405 with ckeditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

**I use CKEditor with laravel,**

- If the user uses the bold icon CkEditor Convert it to (strong) tag, and if submitted the form I have error 405
- If removed (strong) tag everything is good.

*sorry for my English*

```
$("#send_emails").submit(function(e) {
var email_temp= CKEDITOR.instances['emailEditor'].getData();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/sendEmails',
    data: {
        email_temp:email_temp,
        "_token":  $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(response)
    {
       //some code

    }
});
e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Route :
    `Route::post('/sendEmails', 'SendEmeilController@sendEmails');`

Comment: Looks like the method of the form gets modified. Could resend the form using bold icon, capture the request and post it here?

Comment: add your code here

Comment: updated question and added code.